# Ruby: is there a way to get the values from an array using an array of indexs all in one line?

Tags: ruby

```
array: [1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
indexes: [0,3,5,1]
output: [1,1,2,2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
output = array.values_at(*indexes)
```

Note that you have to splat the indexes argument, [values_at](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/values_at) accepts a list of integers or ranges as argument

Comment: BAH! I need to wait 10 minutes to choose this as the answer. =p